# Windows Terminal: disable "follow link"

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-terminal

Since some new version, every single link the output is underlined, with this tooltip:

> Ctrl+Click to follow link

I found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/65b22b9a/src/cascadia/TerminalControl/Resources/en-US/Resources.resw#L178-L180):

```
<data name="HowToOpenRun.Text" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Ctrl+Click to follow link</value>
</data>
```

but I dont see any documentation on how to disable this.

Comment: Do you want to disable the ability to ctl click or the message that pops up?

Comment: I was just hoping to disable the tooltip only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the setting to disable:

```
"experimental.detectURLs": false
```

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.10.2383.0